# Is too much cron jobs schedule cause server time out of website ?

Tags: magento2, database, crontab

Hi i have a website in magento2 , in my database we have **`467500`** rows in **cron_schedule** table , my site is lacking alot and most of the time it goes down displaying server timeout issue .
The configuration of my server is 18gb ram with 1 tb HDD , my database got crashed during the time of when cron jobs run , its my guess it is creating issue .

> i see **462318** statuses are in pending states in my cron_schedule table out of **467500** statuses .

I just wants to know is this creating issue ? **should i delete that all rows in my table for quick heal ?** , as my db is crashing so much , what will be the permanent solution for this ?

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop   for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device  
FOR server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento had an issue where if one of your cron jobs takes longer than a minute to complete, it will keep starting new processes with the same tasks because it only writes the completed task to the database after all cronjobs have finished, causing a large amount of duplicate cronjobs with the status pending.

You could delete all cron jobs that are more than a day old with `DELETE FROM cron_schedule WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`. The fix for this issue is in Magento 2.2.5, so you should upgrade if you haven't yet. If you can't upgrade yet you could run the query above in a daily cronjob as a temporary fix.

Comment: it works , useless crons deleted but the problem is still pressent i think its in my version issue 2.2

Comment: @HamzaMustafa Any chance we could Skype TALK?  Please view my profile, Network profile for contact information including my Skype ID.